# How to use "specific setting blocks in Laravel Voyager admin pages or posts" for frontend implementations?

Tags: laravel, voyager

I am developing a CMS based web application using Laravel's voyager, for block management, I want to implement specific settings on each pages or posts, Is there any specific library?

Comment: you must check the voyger documentation

Comment: The questions is so ambiguous. please send more information about what exactly you need

Comment: I meant specific feature or settings block for each pages like voyager-page-blocks library, created new models and implemented this functionality. Thanks.